# Can't show image in Canvas (Tkinter)

Tags: python, image, canvas, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I've been making a Paint program and now I'm adding an "Open" function. Here was the result five minutes ago:[image: Don't pay attention to the actual drawing]

Don't pay attention to the drawing itself... So I restarted the thing, and this time it just left a blank screen, without showing the image like that...
[image: The result]

Here's the code:

```
def Open():
global Directory
Directory = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/Desktop", title="Open Image", filetypes=(("Portable Network Graphics","*.png"),("Joint Photographic Experts Group","*.jpg"),("all files","*.*")))

ImageOpened = Image.open(Directory)
Largeur, Hauteur = ImageOpened.size

if Largeur >= 1000 or Hauteur >= 1000:
    messagebox.showwarning("Can't open image", "The image is too big!")
elif not Largeur >= 1000 or not Hauteur >= 1000:
    Can.delete(ALL)
    FinalImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(ImageOpened)
    Can.configure(width=Largeur, height=Hauteur)

    WidthPosition = Largeur/2
    WidthPosition = WidthPosition+2

    HeightPosition = Hauteur/2
    HeightPosition = HeightPosition+2

    print (Largeur, Hauteur, WidthPosition, HeightPosition)
    Can.create_image(WidthPosition,HeightPosition, image=FinalImage)
```

Could somebody help me please? ;-;

Comment: What exactly is the problem here? and where did `Can` come from.

Comment: Read [why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm)

Comment: Oh sorry, Can is my Canvas. The problem is that the image isn't showing up...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just resolved it, I forgot a `global` at the beggining... ^^'
So the code looks like this now:

```
def Open():
global Directory, FinalImage
Directory = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/Desktop", title="Open Image", filetypes=(("Portable Network Graphics","*.png"),("Joint Photographic Experts Group","*.jpg"),("all files","*.*")))

ImageOpened = Image.open(Directory)
Largeur, Hauteur = ImageOpened.size

if Largeur >= 1000 or Hauteur >= 1000:
    messagebox.showwarning("Can't open image", "The image is too big!")
elif not Largeur >= 1000 or not Hauteur >= 1000:
    Can.delete(ALL)
    FinalImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(ImageOpened)
    Can.configure(width=Largeur, height=Hauteur)

    WidthPosition = Largeur/2
    WidthPosition = WidthPosition+2

    HeightPosition = Hauteur/2
    HeightPosition = HeightPosition+2

    print (Largeur, Hauteur, WidthPosition, HeightPosition)
    Can.create_image(WidthPosition,HeightPosition, image=FinalImage)
```